# Cart class how to add new item?

Tags: java

In my cart class I am having difficulties adding in a new item into the array. I try SaleItem item = new SaleItem, but it gives me an error because my SaleItem is an abstract which we are supposed to keep the abstract. Some of the parts in the Cart Class is wrong, I wished I know what I am doing. ANy suggestions? or Help?

This is the directions:
**Cart constructor method takes as input an integer parameter that determines the maximum number of items that can be placed in the cart. addItem,that takes five input parameters where the first four inputs represent code, title, price and quantity of the item to be added. The fifth input parameter gives the type of the item (1 Book, 2 Dictionary, 3 AudioCD). According to the type of the item to be added, the method asks theuser for values of the remaining instance variables. The method then instantiate the corresponding object and adds it to the array.
cartTotalCost: a method that returns the total cost of all items in the cart. getNumBooks:a method that returns the number of books in the cart.
getNumCDS:a method that returns the number of Audio CD’s in the cart.
toString:a method that prints a nicely formatted output of the cart where each item is printed in one line.

SaleItem Class:

```
public abstract class SaleItem {
private int code;
private String title;
private double price;
private int quantity;

public SaleItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity){
this.code = code;
this.title = title;
this.price = price;
this.quantity = quantity;
}

//Getters
public int getCode(){
    return this.code;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}
public int getQuantity(){
    return this.quantity;
}
// Setters
public void setCode(int code){
    this.code = code;
}
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price = price;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

//ItemTotalCost method
public double itemTotalCost(){
    double total = this.price * this.quantity;
    return total;
}

//ToString
public String toString(){
    String outputItemDes = "";
    outputItemDes += "Code: "+ this.code;
    outputItemDes += "Title: "+ this.title;
    outputItemDes += "Price: "+ this.price;
    outputItemDes += "Quantity: "+ this.quantity;
    outputItemDes += "Item Total Cost: " + this.itemTotalCost();
    return outputItemDes;
}
```

}

Book Class:

```
public class Book{
private String author;
private int numPages;

public Book(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String author, int numPages){
    this.author = author;
    this.numPages = numPages;
}

//Getters
public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
}
public int getNumPages(){
    return this.numPages;
}

//Setters
public void setAuthor(String author){
    this.author = author;
}
public void setNumPages(int numPages){
    this.numPages = numPages;
}

//toString
@Override
public String toString(){
    String outputBookDes = "";
    outputBookDes += "Author: "+ this.author;
    outputBookDes += "Number Pages: "+ this.numPages;
    return outputBookDes;
}
```

}

AudioCD Class:

```
public class AudioCD extends SaleItem {
private String artist;
private String label;
private int playingTime;

public AudioCD(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, String artist, String label, int playingTime){
    super(code,title,price,quantity);
    this.artist = artist;
    this.label = label;
    this.playingTime = playingTime;
}

//Getters
public String getArtist(){
    return this.artist;
}
public String getLabel(){
    return this.label;
}
public int getPlayingTime(){
    return this.playingTime;
}

//Setters
public void setArtist(String artist){
    this.artist = artist;
}
public void setLabel(String label){
    this.label = label;
}
public void setPlayingTime(int playingTime){
    this.playingTime = playingTime;
}

//toSting method as in the Book class
@Override
public String toString(){
    String outputAudioDes = "";
    outputAudioDes += "Artist: "+ this.artist;
    outputAudioDes += "Label: "+ this.label;
    outputAudioDes += "Playing Time: "+ this.playingTime;
    return outputAudioDes;
}
```

}

Cart CLass:

```
public class Cart {
// Variables
private SaleItem[] itemList;
private int numItems;
private Book book;
private Dictionary dictionary;
private AudioCD audioCD;

//Constructors
public Cart(int maxItems){
    this.numItems = 0;
    this.itemList = new SaleItem[maxItems];
}
//Setters
public void setBook(Book book){
    this.book = book;
}
public void setDictionary(Dictionary dictionary){
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
}
public void setAudioCD(AudioCD audioCD){
    this.audioCD = audioCD;
}
//Add Item method goes into the cart
public void addItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, int itemNum){
    int maxItems = this.itemList.length;

    if (itemNum == 1){
        System.out.println(book);
        }
    else if (itemNum == 2){
        System.out.println(dictionary);
    }
    else if (itemNum == 3){
        System.out.println(audioCD);
    }

    if (this.numItems < maxItems){
        SaleItem item = new SaleItem(code,title,price,quantity,itemNum);
        itemList[this.numItems] = item;
        this.numItems++;
    }
}
// Sums up all of the item in the cart
public double cartTotalCost(){
    double cartTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
        SaleItem item = itemList[i];
        double subTotal = (item.getPrice() * item.getQuantity());
        cartTotal += subTotal;
    }
    return cartTotal;
}
//Getters
public Book getNumBooks(){
    return book;
}
public AudioCD getNumCDS(){
    return audioCD;
}
public String toString(){
    String cartDes = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++){
        cartDes += itemList[i];
    }
    return cartDes;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post only relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment you're working on is attempting to either introduce you to or strengthen your skills with inheritance. `SaleItem` is to remain abstract because the items that are for sale are supposed to inherit the properties of `SaleItem`. `SaleItem` is not to be instantiated as if it were, say, an `AudioCD`.

You can address an `AudioCD` as a `SaleItem` because `AudioCD` is a child class of `SaleItem`. This would be done like this:

```
SaleItem saleItem = new AudioCD(Object parameter, Object parameter2, ...);
```

Take a look at [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) documentation or [BeginnersBook's](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/inheritance-in-java/) documentation for inheritance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix my errors, since I want the public void addItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity, int itemNum) whatever the parameters that I put in my main to be added in my arrays not by adding an Book as into my method in my Cart class.

Answer (score 0):

A CD or a Book are both types of sale items. You can not the call SaleItem() constructor - you must call a constructor of a implementation of sale item (like a CD or a Book). Thus if you want to make a new sale item, first decide what type you want to make and then do something like:

```
SaleItem item = new Book(0, "BookTitle", 5.99, 1, "Author", 500);
```

Obviously the arguments in this case would depend on the specific book you are trying to create.

As for the assignment, it sounds like you need to ask the user for all of the info needed to create the proper object within your addItem method. So for a book, you would ask for the author, number of pages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, Book must extend SaleItem.

The most trivial way to instantiate the appropriate SaleItem is inside the ifs statements above:
If itemNum == 1
    item = new Book() with the params.
Same for the others.

Why do you keep references to a specific book, dictionary and cd in Cart? The only usage I see for them is that you are trying to count the number of books in the cart. If thats what you meant, that is not the way. You should instead iterate over the items array and count the book instances

Answer (score -1):

"The fifth input parameter gives the type of the item (1 Book, 2 Dictionary, 3 AudioCD). According to the type of the item to be added, the method asks theuser for values of the remaining instance variables."

You aren't supposed to create a new `SaleItem`, you're supposed to take the 5th input to determine what kind of `SaleItem` you are supposed to instantiate and add to the cart.

Your code `SaleItem item = new SaleItem(code,title,price,quantity,itemNum);` is wrong anyways.

Your `SaleItem` constructor is `public SaleItem(int code, String title, double price, int quantity)` so you aren't even passing the right number of parameters.